# Symfony 4 - Template issue css displayed

Tags: php, css, symfony, twig, symfony4

I just uploaded my website on ovh and a problem occured when all was right on localhost. Indeed, my templates were all displayed as I wanted. Now that the website is on the server, the half of the webpages are not displaying the templates but their own CSS code !

Here are my MainController and the Template on a page that displays right :

```
/**
* @Route("/", name="home")
*/
public function home()
{
    $home = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Homepage::class)
        ->find(1);
    return $this->render('main/home.html.twig', [
        'home' => $home,
    ]);
}
```

Template

```
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}
{% block title %} Fuzz Design {% endblock title %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ 'homepage.css' }}">
{% endblock stylesheets %}
{% block body %} .... {% endblock %}
```

And here is the MainController portion for a page  displaying the CSS instead :

```
/**
* @Route("/about", name="about")
*/
public function about()
{
    $about = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(About::class)
        ->find(1);

    $projets = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Project::class)
        ->findBy(
            array(),
            array('id' => 'DESC'),
            3
        );

    return $this->render('main/about.html.twig', [
        'about' => $about,
        'projets'=>$projets,
    ]);
}
```

Template

```
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Fuzz Design : A Propos{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ 'about.css' }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ 'animation_hover.css' }}">
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}.... {% endblock %}
```

I am almost sure that I do it the same way, but the first one displays the template, when the other displays the css stylesheet code.

Has anyone any idea of the reason why I obtain such a weird behavior ? And how to fix it ?

Comment: How is it rendered when you view the page source? Are your links tags correct?

Comment: The view source is the same as what I can see on the "normal" page :  @media (min-width: 1001px) {
    body {
        background-image: url("Imge_background.jpg");
        background-size: 100% auto;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }
    h4 { ...

Comment: Can you post the code of the layout?

Comment: Ok it seems that if I change the name of the stylesheets there is no more problem... It seems it is a problem of name conflict. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a name conflict.

Try to change the name of your css file like : banana.css and make the corresponding call in your template.

It could work =)